# How to decode Cyrillic WINDOWS-1251 string to unicode using python

Tags: python, unicode

I have a very large (2.5 GB) text file with Cyrillic characters in various encodings, including Windows-1251:

> =D0=A0=D0=B2=D0=B8=D1=81=D1=8C =D0=B2 =D0=B0=D1=82=D0=B0=D0=BA=D1=83 =D0=BD=
>   =D0=B0 =C2=AB=D0=9F=D0=B5=D1=80=D1=88=D0=B8=D0=BD=D0=B3=D0=B5=C2=BB

I have already tried .encode() and .decode() with various combinations of encodings, but I cannot get the text to be readable. I have also tried reading in binary mode.

```
with open('myfile.mbox', 'r') as f:
    unreadable_str = f.readline()

unreadable_str.encode('WINDOWS-1251').decode('utf-8')
```

I thought it would encode the string into bytes using the Windows encoding and then give it back as readable Unicode, but instead, it always outputs the same string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That data is encoded according to [RFC 1522](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1522.html).  The [quopri](https://docs.python.org/3/library/quopri.html) module can be used to decode the data to bytes, which look like UTF-8-encoded data:

```
>>> s='''=D0=A0=D0=B2=D0=B8=D1=81=D1=8C =D0=B2 =D0=B0=D1=82=D0=B0=D0=BA=D1=83 =D0=BD= =D0=B0 =C2=AB=D0=9F=D0=B5=D1=80=D1=88=D0=B8=D0=BD=D0=B3=D0=B5=C2=BB'''
>>> quopri.decodestring(s).decode('utf8')
'Рвись в атаку н= а «Першинге»'
```